# Why does my GCP server fail to start services after an auto restart?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, server

I have an **e2-medium** GCP ubuntu server running my application, and from time to time I get auto restarts, when that happens, the server does not successfully restart, preventing me from ssh until I manually stop and start the server from GCP.

I took a look at my logs and found I had the following errors:

`earlyBootReportEvent:`
`{ insertId: "1" jsonPayload: {3} logName: "projects/<app>/logs/compute.googleapis.com%2Fshielded_vm_integrity" receiveTimestamp: "2022-01-03T06:41:42.273102812Z" resource: {2} severity: "ERROR" timestamp: "2022-01-03T06:41:40.265022276Z” }`

`lateBootReportEvent:`
`{ insertId: "2" jsonPayload: {3} logName: "projects/<app>/logs/compute.googleapis.com%2Fshielded_vm_integrity" receiveTimestamp: "2022-01-03T06:41:47.520596790Z" resource: {2} severity: "ERROR" timestamp: "2022-01-03T06:41:45.512413302Z” }`

Following the instructions here https://cloud.google.com/compute/shielded-vm/docs/integrity-monitoring#updating-baseline I have eliminated the error above, but my vm still fails to start all services after auto restart.

Comment: You should edit your post with which services are in question and if you are using  ~/.config/autostart. Also I recommend taking a look at [startup scripts][1]

  [1]: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/startup-scripts/linux

Comment: Hi @Notauser, the restarts seem to be enforced by GCP itself. I have plans to include my own auto-restarts, but these ones are carried out by GCP it would seem.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]" along with [mcve] and their linked pages. Your question isn't asked well, and appears to be off-topic because SO is for questions related to code and applications that are closely related to writing code, whereas your question is about running a server which would be in a different site. https://stackexchange.com/sites